# React js simple and light weight Date Picker

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create an input box with a date picker for the user's Date of Birth. I do not need date range - Just a date picker that writes date in yyyymmdd format.

There are many options that are heavy but a light one will benefit future searchers as well. I tried using the following but many have external dependencies like momentjs and some do not even work

1. react-day-picker
2. react-datepicker
3. react-flatpicker
4. react-inifnite-calendar
5. .. more

I do not want to include jQuery in my react app so anything that needs jQuery is not an option. I searched for over 3 hours, installed many libraries and could not find any light weight options. I dont care about the looks as I can style my own css.

How to implement a simple date picker in a react app without using any external dependencies such as momentjs ?

Here is my component code that right now does not include the date picker as I deleted all options I installed.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
...
...
import MyCustomDateInput from './date-input'
...
...
class EditProfile extends Component {
  state = {
...
...
date: '',
...
...

render() {
let {
...
...
date
} = this.state

....
....
  return (
      <div>
        <Title
          value="Edit profile"
          desc="Edit your profile, add tags and information"
        />
...
...
<MyCustomDateInput/>
...
...
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

Comment: @Bigga_HD - As mentioned in my question - react-datepicker uses momentjs which is very heavy. Just for one input Date picker I would not install such huge libraries.

Comment: https://github.com/coderhaoxin/react-flatpickr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is light enough :) **No library**. Just a simple `JS` function while taking advantage of `HTML5`. Sidenote, a valid date is `yyyy/mm/dd` and that's what you see displayed here. For more [info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Using_date_inputs) .
But you get your date picker and you can do with the value whatever you want. Hope this was helpful.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>A demonstration of how to access a Date field</h3>

<input type="date" id="myDate" value="mm-dd-yyyy">

<button onclick="datePicker()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function datePicker() {
    let d = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes - Thats awesome,.. No libraries, no junk.. Just whats needed., Do you mind if I style this up, beautify it, create a react component and post in Githhub for free ?

Comment: No man, of course not. Do your thing ;)
I'm just glad it was helpful. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. Quick question - Is the TryIt button supposed to work ? It does nothing.

Comment: I see. I thought that was to pop up the calendar.. Thats more of a submit button.. Thanks.